# Gson on Android: Is it possible to only parse part of the json result, ignoring the rest?

Tags: android, json, gson

I tried searching for an answer to my question, but I haven't been able so far so I'm hopeing one of you might be able to shed some light on my problem.

For my app I need to parse a JSON response which contains 3 different types of objects, namely Icons, Header and Player.

For now, only the Icons objects are required since the Player and Header classes won't be added untill a later date. So I was wondering, is it possible to parse this response and only focus on the Icons objects, ignoring the other two?
I've run into problems parsing JSON responses before where GSON couldn't parse the data unless everything was correctly labeled so I'm not sure whether or not my idea is even possible.

Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Regards,

Sander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) parser is an option to you? It is possible with it.

Comment: It might be, although the rest of the app uses GSON at the moment. Would it be a problem using two parsers in one app? I would understand if that might cause some difficulties.

Comment: What kind of problems? You can use one parser for one type of data, another one for another. Anyway, if performance is an issue jackson is a way to do. If not, you can stick with GSON and don't care about overhead.